# How can I use an array map of routes with BrowserRouter and Switch without them all loading at once?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Routes:

```
const issueSubmissionModal = () => IssueModal({ isVisible: true })
const renderHeader = () => <AppHeader userData={userData}><AppNavbar/></AppHeader>
const renderHome = () => <AppTemplate userData={userData} />
 const Routes = userData ? [
        {
            key: "home",
            path: "/",
            component: renderHome(),
            includeProfile:  null,
            includeAppheader: renderHeader()
        },
       
        {
            key: "issueSubmission",
            path: "/issueSubmission",
            component: issueSubmissionModal(),
            includeProfile: renderHome(),
            includeAppheader: renderHeader()
        },
    ] : []

    const renderRoutes = () => <Switch>
    {Routes.map(route => (
    <Route exact path={route.path} key={route.key}>
    {route.includeProfile && route.includeProfile}
    {route.component}
    </Route>
    ))}
    </Switch>

return renderRoutes();
```

App.tsx:

```
function App() {
  const { data: userData, isLoading, isError, error } = useAppUser();
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        {userData ? 
            <Routes userData={userData} />
           : null}
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Problem? No matter what I do, all routes render as soon as the page launches. I simplified to two routes here, but the actual app has several.
It seems to me Switch isn't working. I don't know why.
I can go back to just having all the routes written out manually in App.tsx, but that's gross and inefficient for what we're trying to do.

Any React gurus got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing to include component tag within `<Route />`

```
 {
   Routes.map(route => (
    <Route exact path={route.path} key={route.key} component= 
  {route.includeProfile ? route.component} />
   )
  )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately, the component tag makes no difference. It still renders everything at once.